# Question about Win7 64 bit

Tags: c++, dll, windows-7, mfc

I have a 32 bit C++/MFC application (X) that loads a DLL.

I have another 32 bit .NET 3.5 application (Y) that loads the same DLL.

When I test these applications under Windows 7 64 Bit, X loads the DLL without 
any problems. But Y crashes as soon as it attempts to call a function 
from the DLL.

My question is: What can I do to make Y work properly.

Do I need some kind of special commands to indicate that it is a 32 bit DLL?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

jfronner

Comment: When you say '32 bit .net 3.5 application', can you check whether it is MSIL or x86. You might be better off compiling to x86.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when things "crash" there is an error message. This error message is often useful. In the absence of this message I am reduced to guessing.

I guess that your .net app targets "AnyCPU" and so on the 64 bit machine it runs as a 64 bit process. A 64 bit process cannot load a 32 bit DLL. If you switch it to target "32 bit" then it will all work again.

Or you could compile your DLL to 64 bit but that may be more tricky.

Comment: @jfronner Did this answer (or Patrick's identical one) help solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your .Net application as being platform-neutral, it will execute your app as 32-bit on a 32-bit platform, and as 64-bit on a 64-bit platform.

In the latter case, your app will probably crash when it tries to load the 32-bit DLL because 64-bit apps can only load 64-bit DLL's.

Compile your .Net app as 32-bit explicitly.